# list of all friends C# Facebook SDK v5

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

Can you please give me the code for getting the list of all friends for a user?

Then How can I send an invitation to use my app, or send a comment to one of the friends?

Please don't tell me to look in the API, I want to learn how the C# SKD v5 should be used. Can anyone provide some code samples for this? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am going to answer this one part at a time.
the example I am writing uses dynamics so it requires .Net Framework 4.0 if using 3.5 this would need to be done with Dictionary.

the key to getting at your friends info is the Perm friends_about_me 
here is a list of all perms you can ask for.
[Facebook Permissions List](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/)

> Can you please give me the code for getting the list of all friends for a user?

```
    var auth = new CanvasAuthorizer { Perms = "user_about_me,friends_about_me" };

    if (auth.Authorize())
    {
        var fb = new FacebookClient(auth.Session.AccessToken);
        dynamic myInfo = fb.Get("/me/friends");
        foreach (dynamic friend in myInfo.data  )
        {
            Response.Write("Name: " + friend.name + "<br/>Facebook id: " + friend.id + "<br/><br/>");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I will look into the second question about sending app request and post back.

Comment: your answare shed me some light. I would strongly appreciate the answare to the second part. The first half is excellent. Thanks allot!

Comment: I still have not got the invitations to work server side. On my sites I use the JavaScript SDK to send invites. I will try to figure this out and get back with you all.

Comment: Thanks for your time. If you have any other code samples, maybe some copy-paste from your site would help me alot. Please send anything here or on my email : ryan.popa@yahoo.com . As I said, any samples would help me alot because I can't find anything else than basic authentication!

Comment: This might sound odd but I never looked at the SDK more than a month ago. Most of what I have done is for work so i can't post our code. If you have questions I will do what I can to come up with an answer. The one thing I can say is if you want to know how to use the SDK get to know PHP so you can read there examples.